# How do I transform every doc in a large Mongodb collection without map/reduce?

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce

Apologies for the longish description.

I want to run a transform on every doc in a large-ish Mongodb collection with 10 million records approx 10G. Specifically I want to apply a geoip transform to the ip field in every doc and either append the result record to that doc or just create a whole other record linked to this one by say id (the linking is not critical, I can just create a whole separate record).  Then I want to count and group by say city - (I do know how to do the last part).

The major reason I believe I cant use map-reduce is I can't call out to the geoip library in my map function (or at least that's the constraint I believe exists).

So I the central question is how do I run through each record in the collection apply the transform - using the most efficient way to do that.

Batching via Limit/skip is out of question as it does a "table scan" and it is going to get progressively slower.

Any suggestions?

Python or Js preferred just bec I have these geoip libs but code examples in other languages welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to go over "each record", you'll do one full table scan anyway, then a simple cursor (`find()`) + maybe only fetching few fields (_id, ip) should do it. python driver will do the batching under the hood, so maybe you can give a hint on what's the optimal batch size (`batch_size`) if the default is not good enough.

If you add a new field and it doesn't fit the previously allocated space, mongo will have to move it to another place, so you might be better off creating a new document.

Comment: OK, thanks much for that - did not know about the batching by driver - I looked at the API and I see that now - thanks very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am also attempting another approach in parallel (as plan B) which is to use mongoexport.  I use it with --csv to dump a large csv file with just the (id, ip) fields.  Then the plan is to use a python script to do a geoip lookup and then post back to mongo as a new doc on which map-reduce can now be run for count  etc.  Not sure if this is faster or the cursor is.  We'll see.